# ¿Como usar recyclerview + spinner como item en kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Buen dia, estoy aprendiendo a programar en android usando kotlin, quiero poner un spinner con informacion como item y que cada vez que se presione un boton "agregar" cree otro item con otro spinner con la misma informacion.

**en mi clase adapter en el metodo:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewholder_pedidos, position: Int){
        val item=lista_datos_pedidos[position]
        holder.render(item)


        val tallas= arrayOf("Sin Talla","XCH","CH","M","G","EG","2X","3X")
        val lista_predeter= ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,tallas)
        holder.spinn?.adapter=lista_predeter


    }
```

intento agregar la informacion al spinner pero me marca error en el ArrayAdapter
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien podria orientarme?
gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema indica que el constructor que usas no es el adecuado, pero esto es debido al valor del contexto que es incorrecto, aquí no debes usar `this`.

Realiza esta solución:

Primeramente, declara una variable global:

```
var context : Context
```

Dentro de `onCreateViewHolder()` asigna su valor obteniendo el valor del contexto de la variable `parent`:

```
@Override
... onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
     ...
     ...
    context = parent.getContext();
    ...
    ...
}
```

ahora puedes usar el valor de la variable `context` (que contiene el contexto) para instanciar el `ArrayAdapter`:

```
val tallas= arrayOf("Sin Talla","XCH","CH","M","G","EG","2X","3X")
val lista_predeter= ArrayAdapter(context , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,tallas)
```